# Start GCP CentOS VPS on schedule?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, centos8

Is it possible to reliably start a CentOS VPS on Google cloud on schedule (say every monday 2pm) ?
And then shut it down after 60 min.

*To avoid extra charges the VPS needs to be shutdown not suspended (eg `poweroff`).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) to learn how instance schedules let you start and stop virtual machine (VM) instances automatically.